# Java Map vs Backend database. Which is better for speed and for multithreading for relations?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, dictionary, time-complexity

My algorithm will likely not be used on the web. The object I describe may be used by multiple threads, however.

The original object I had designed emulated pointers.

Reduced, a symbol would map to multiple pointers, and each unique pointer would map to a single symbol.

When I was finally finished and had a working algorithm, it turns out I actually needed six maps in total (these maps are called tens of thousands of times).

Initial testing with a very very small sample set of symbols showed the program to be working very efficiently. However, I'm afraid that once I increase the number of symbols by a few thousand-fold it will become sluggish.

Once the program completes and closes, the pointers do not need to persist.

I was wondering if I should re implement my algorithm using a database as a backend. Would this be better than using all of these maps?

The maps are stored in memory. The database will be stored on a hard drive (I have a SSD, so I'm afraid there will be a large difference in performance on my machine vs a machine using SATA/PATA). The maps should also be O(1). The maps might also become very ugly once multithreading is introduced, unless I use thread safe mapping, which would slow the program down. A database would efficiently handle these tasks.

I've formally written out the proper relations, and I'm sure I can implement it in a database if that was the best option. Which is the better option?

Comment: "*I'm afraid that once I increase the number of symbols by a few thousand-fold it will become sluggish.*" => why? As you mentioned maps are O(1).

Comment: The maps are O(1), but how does that apply to concurrent maps? I've never used them. Memory management? How efficient are they in a db vs vm?

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is O(1) too. Instead of guessing what it may or may not look like, the only answer to your question is to test various ways - but if you find that a Hard Drive based DB is more efficient, then you have probably messed up your mapping algorithm!

Answer (score 0):

Hard drives, even fast, are several orders of magnitude slower than your memory. So if your goal is performance you should stay in memory and use maps. For thread safety you can just use a ConcurrentHashMap which uses a lock-free algorithm and the synchronisation penalty in a multi threaded environment should be minimal.

You should also check if a single thread does not provide enough performance - multiple threads always introduce some overhead and they need to bring enough gains to offset it.

You may also want to check in-memory DBs such as [`HyperSQL`](http://hsqldb.org/) or [`H2 Database`](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need not to persist that data structure, do not try to support it on a database.  In your place, I would try some load tests with a proper amount of data on the data structure you already have and try to refine it from there if performance was not what I expected.

Anyway, the trend currently is to use relational databases in hard disk for persistence and cache frequently queried data in "big hashtables" in memory for performance, I doubt falling back to a database would improve your performance

Answer (score 0):

If your data structures fit in memory, I would be shocked if using a database would be faster (not even considering the complexity of using a database implementation). By throwing away all the assumptions, features, safety and consistency that a database must maintain, you will gain performance.  Even the best DB implementation, assuming enough memory to cache everything, pretty much has a `ConcurrentHashMap` as an upper bound on performance. As a practical matter, you won't get CHM performance even with great caching, because a DB API will require defensive copies or cache invalidations that you can avoid with your in-memory structure.

Apart from the likely performance boost simply from using an in-memory hashmap, you may also get additional performance by tuning your structure based on your specific use case.  For example, perhaps the initial lookup is multi-threaded, but individual values are only accessed by a single thread. In that case, you can avoid locking those values.